# Why does my build of gcc not support shared libraries

Tags: linux, gcc, arm

I have built gcc-4.9.0 in a Debian Lenny chroot, on a Debian Wheezy host. The arch=Armel (Wheezy and Lenny). 
I have used the following configure options:

`$PWD/../gcc-4.9.0/configure --prefix=/usr/local/GCC-4.9.0 --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-arch=armv4t --with-float=soft --enable-checking=release --enable-shared --build=arm-linux-gnueabi --host=arm-linux-gnueabi --target=arm-linux-gnueabi LDFLAGS=-Wl,-no-keep-memory --disable-libjava`

When I try to build some libs (libgcrypt in this example) I am not able to build shared libraries:

```
checking whether the /usr/local/GCC-4.9.0/bin/gcc linker (/usr/local/GCC-4.9.0/bin/gcc) supports shared libraries... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... unsupported
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... no
checking whether to build shared libraries... no
checking whether to build static libraries... yes`
```

And for Curl:

```
gcc: error: ../lib/.libs/libcurl.so: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [Makefile:923: curl] Error 1
```

Am I still missing some configure option(s) when building gcc?

Comment: There should be a `config.log` file in the directory you ran `./configure` from while trying to build libgcrypt.  That file will give you more info about what ran and possibly why it failed.

Comment: Libgcrypt built but with static libs instead of shared. The config.log only confirms this by stating that the linker (gcc) does not support shared libraries.

Comment: What does the `config.log` say _exactly_? there should be a test of some sort that `./configure` does to determine shared libraries support, it does not get that information from thin air.  Usually the `config.log` file indicates at what `./configure` lines the test runs.

Comment: `checking whether the /usr/local/GCC-4.9.0/bin/gcc linker (/usr/local/GCC-4.9.0/bin/gcc) supports shared libraries... no` is weird — linker should normally be `ld`.

Comment: Thank you Patrice, well spotted. The problem was that linker was incorrectly pointing to gcc instead of ld (a typo on my part)

Comment: Happy to help.  I'll repost as a real answer, as prescribed in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294791/what-if-i-answer-a-question-in-a-comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

`checking whether the /usr/local/GCC-4.9.0/bin/gcc linker (/usr/local/GCC-4.9.0/bin/gcc) supports shared libraries... no`

is weird — linker should normally be `ld`.